# CentOS 7 does not detect partition

Tags: centos, partition, system-installation

I am trying to install CentOS 7 in dual boot with Windows 10. I pre-partitioned my HD (C: 500 GB total), separating a drive (P: 60GB) for CentOS, but in the installation, it does not detect the partition (P). How can I add it to the installation options?

Comment: what do you see in there,  fdisk -l output

Comment: Go back into Windows and delete the P: volume and leave it as unallocated space. Run the installer for CentOS7 again and the space will be available for install.

Comment: I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Go back into Windows and delete the P: volume and leave it as unallocated space. Run the installer for CentOS 7 again and the space will be available for install.